# Как выровнять div по горизонтали?

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
div.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
/* .logo img {
  display: block;
} */
.call {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
}
ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://pavlova.cc/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/sobakapavlova-logo-100x100.png" alt="собака павлова">
<div class="call">
  <ul>
    <li>8-800-000-00-00</li>
    <li>skype: <strong>dog pavlov</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Который из div'ов вам нужно выровнять, и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу... :

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  
  text-align: center;
}
div.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* .logo img {
  display: block;
} */
.call {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://pavlova.cc/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/sobakapavlova-logo-100x100.png" alt="собака павлова">
</div>
<div class="call">
  <ul>
    <li>8-800-000-00-00</li>
    <li>skype: <strong>dog pavlov</strong></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: как поставить данные блоки в одну строк?

Comment: @ShuklinAlexey, какие блоки, уточняйте? А лучше сразу вопрос правильно сформулировать, что Вам нужно и что не получается!

Comment: подскажите, как в данном случае поставить блок .call вслед за блоком .logo (что бы в одной строке находились)

Comment: @ShuklinAlexey, поправила код. так или опять не то?)

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Процентный способ:

```
#test {
  margin:0 25% 0 25%;
  width:50%;
}
```

Смешанный

```
#test {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

С доп. блоком

```
#dop-block{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 50%;
}
#block{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
}
```